# Fail test on Exception in JSR223 postprocessor

Tags: jmeter

In my Jmeter (2.13) I have a piece of Java code in a JSR223 postprocessor. The code throws a Nullpointerexception, but the test will still report ok.

How can I report a failed Jmeter test when an exception occurs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by calling the following code line:

```
prev.setSuccessful(false);
```

Example usage:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Failure", ex);
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    prev.setResponseMessage(ex.getMessage());
    throw ex;
}
```

`prev` is a shorthand to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all associated SampleResult methods and fields.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article to learn more about using Java and JMeter API from scripting test elements. Pre-defined variables like `prev`, `vars`, `ctx` and so on are common for all scripting test elements.